# Getting value form dynatically added element

Tags: reactjs

I have initialized a state object to store the dynamically added input elements by a user via a button they click. In this input element, a user can type a number. I'm trying to get the number value and value of every element that is dynamically added but I am not sure how to exactly do that.

My code:

```
   const [addedExpenses, setAddedExpenses] = useState([]);

   function addExpense() {
      const userNewExpense = (
         <div class ="new-expense">
            <input id="written-expense"></input>
              <input id="money-expense" ></input>
        </div>
    )
    setAddedExpenses([...addedExpenses, userNewExpense])
```

Comment: I assume you're still new to react. is it correct ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one.

```
export default function App(){
const [addedExpenses, setAddedExpenses] = useState([{values:''}]);/*using the state object to store the dynamically */
const [addedExpensessingle, setAddedExpensessingle] = useState('');/*using the state to store the dynamically */
const handleinput = (e) => {

setAddedExpenses({...addedExpenses,values:e.target.value})
setAddedExpensessingle(e.target.value)
}
return (
<div className="App">
              <input id="written-expense" onChange={handleinput}></input
<p>{addedExpenses.values}</p>
<p>{addedExpensessingle}</p></div>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this satisfies your question. [React-StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-17fhgv?description=A%20create-react-app%20project%20based%20on%20react%20and%20react-dom&file=src%2FApp.js&title=React%20Starter) . StackOverflow already has a similar question try exploring more before posting here.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './style.css';
export default function App() {
  const [expensesCount, setExpensesCount] = useState(1);
  const [inputVal, setInputValue] = useState([{ id: 0, val: '' }]);
  const AddNew = () => {
    setExpensesCount((pre) => pre + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Add New" onClick={AddNew} />
      <br />
      <div>
        {Array.from(Array(expensesCount)).map((item, i) => {
          return (
            <AddExpenses
              i={i}
              onInputChange={(e) => {
                setInputValue((old) =>
                  old.map((item) => ({ id: i, val: e.target.value }))
                );
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function AddExpenses({ onInputChange, i }) {
  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="number"
        onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
        placeholder={i + ' - Input '}
      />
      <br />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

  const ExpenseInput = ({ id, index }) => {
    return (
      <input
        id={id}
        type="text"
        placeholder="Expense"
        style={{ margin: 8 }}
        onChange={(e) => {
          let array = values;
          array[index] = e.target.value;
          setValues(array);
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  //You get values of all inputs from here
  console.log("Values Expense = ", values);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Total elements"
        onChange={(e) => {
          const size = Number(e.target.value);
          setCount(size);
          setValues(new Array(size));
        }}
      />

      <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
        {count > 0 &&
          Array(count)
            .fill(null)
            .map((_, i) => <ExpenseInput id={"expense-" + i} index={i} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Or you can see the live JS :
[Live sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-sea-xljdsf?file=/src/App.js:0-1098)